# Converting multiple zip files into regular folders

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can anyone help me to convert a lot of zip files at once using python?

I have "Years" folder which has 3 folders of "2019","2020" and "2021". Folder "2019" has folders of "1","2","3" folders. Folder "1" has "attachment.zip", Folder "2" has "attachment.zip"  and Folder "3" has "attachment.zip. I want to go through each folder in order to convert all zip files and extract them to "Extracted" folder.
Result should look like this:

Folder "1" has "attachment.zip" and folder of "Extracted".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0):

> Below is the code that worked for me:

```
    import os, zipfile

dir_name = 'C:\\SomeDirectory'
extension = ".zip"

os.chdir(dir_name) # change directory from working dir to dir with files

for item in os.listdir(dir_name): # loop through items in dir
    if item.endswith(extension): # check for ".zip" extension
        file_name = os.path.abspath(item) # get full path of files
        zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(file_name) # create zipfile object
        zip_ref.extractall(dir_name) # extract file to dir
        zip_ref.close() # close file
        os.remove(file_name) # delete zipped file
```

> Looking back at the code I had amended, the directory was getting
> confused with the directory of the script.
>
> The following also works while not ruining the working directory.
> First remove the line

`os.chdir(dir_name)` # change directory from working dir to dir with files

> Then assign `file_name` as

```
file_name = dir_name + "/" + item
```